# Android layout over more linearlayouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create layout like on the image

3 green layouts are linearlayouts and code is shown below.
Can some one give give me code for other red layouts over this three green. What type of layout should be ?

[image]

```
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to put all your overlapping layouts into a Relative layout. So to re-create something similar to your picture do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp" 
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp">
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp" 
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp">
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

`RelativeLayout` is generally used to overlap other layouts.  In this case, you can put your `LinearLayouts` into a `RelativeLayout` then add the other two layouts accordingly as children of the parent `RelativeLayout`.

Example:

```
<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

There are many other attributes you can apply to the children that `RelativeLayout` will respond to, but that don't seem to apply to what you were asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RelativeLayout on the top of the whole layout hierarchy. The first layout in it will be the linear layout, which will will the whole relative layout. Above that, you can put another layouts, which will be placed next in the relative layout. You can align them as you want with aligment according to parent or acoording to each other. good luck